# Hive how is a group defined when calculating a functional group (Max, Min..) when scalar data is used in the same row?

Tags: apache, hadoop, hive

In Hive a statement like this:

```
SELECT MIN('FOO') AS id, 
       MIN('Foo') as name;
```

will return a result set like this:

```
+------------+---------+
|    id     |  name    |
+------------+---------+
|    Foo    |   Foo    |
+------------+---------+
```

Even though I would expect :

```
FOO, Foo
```

(the Max('FOO') is the max value over a group of 1 and the Max('Foo') is the max value over another group of 1).

Using more than one function or appending a ' ' to one of the values produces the expected result.

```
SELECT MIN('FOO') AS id, 
       Max('Foo') as name;
```

or

```
SELECT MIN('FOO') AS id, 
       MIN(concat('Foo', '')) as name;
```

Is this a bug or does grouping in Hive work at a row level over all columns in the row with the same function case insensitively.

Comment: It seems to be a bug

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `hive.cache.expr.evaluation=false`
This might be related to [this](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-7314) bug in Hive.